# Link between tile server and QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapnik, server, centos

I just installed a tiles server in a VM following [this](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://gis-lab.info/qa/mod_tile.html&usg=ALkJrhis6odWAMEf7Pqotr85KI5V7G8f6w) tutorial, everything seems to work. I can see the image exemple on http://localhost/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png like it's supposed to be...

Now, I would like to "open" my tiles in QGIS, using WMS (or whatever) protocol.

I'm new in GIS and a bit lost about what I'm supposed to do.

So, I'm using CentOS 6.x, mod_tile, renderd, mapnik, osm2pgsql and a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TileLayerPlugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/TileLayerPlugin/) is designed for your workcase.

Available tilesets are defined in a **TAB** delimited text file.

The author offers this file for Openstreetmap tiles: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/minorua/78f619fca0dd21b97401/raw/36a413a1b173c2c5860752e003ee5009147a5805/OpenStreetMap.tsv

The file should be self-explaining, and can easily be expanded. My file looks like this:

```
Topo    Topo    file:///F:/Tiles/Topo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png   1   0   16  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
myMapnik    myMapnik    file:///F:/Tiles/myMapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png   1   0   15  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
WanderTopo  WanderTopo  file:///F:/Tiles/WanderTopo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png 1   0   15  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
PDA PDA file:///F:/Tiles/PDA/{z}/{x}/{y}.png    0   0   6   -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
Google  Google  http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}    1   0   20  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
Openstreetmap   OSM http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png 1   0   19  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
lonviaHiking    lonvia  http://tile.waymarkedtrails.org/hiking/{z}/{x}/{y}.png  1   0   20  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
lonviaCycling   lonvia  http://tile.waymarkedtrails.org/cycling/{z}/{x}/{y}.png 1   0   20  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
Arcgis  Arcgis  http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png   1   0   16  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
Googlesv    Googlesv    https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US&lyrs=svv|cb_client:apiv3&style=40,18&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}  1   0   20  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

Datasets can be folder structures on your disk, localhost, or any tile-serving web URL, as long as the [tile naming scheme](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) of OpenStreetMap is used.

Comment: When I try to fill "external layer definition directory" with my server URL nothing appears in the list...

Comment: That's not the intended use. By clicking on the 3-dot-icon, you can select a folder where the tab-separated file is placed. Default is `C:\users\<username>\.qgis2\python\plugins\TileLayerPlugin\layers`. You can take `frame.tsv`, and add a line inside with layer name, URL, zoom levels etc.

Comment: Okay, I'm supposed to edit frame.tsv ? how do I get the Title, Attribution, zoom, etc informations ?

Comment: Take the tsv file from the author linked above, open it with a good text editor like Notepad++, copy the last line, change the titel and attribution as you like and enter your URL where the OSM URL is. Instead of 0/0/0.png, the `{z}/{x}/{y}.png` should remain. Then put the tsv file next to the frame.tsv, or choose a different folder.

Comment: Okay I understand, I added 
"Test Test http://xx.xx.xx.xx/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" but nothing appeared             EDIT: my bad, I forgot to add the x,y,z positions !

Comment: thanks for your help, do you know how I get an access to the layer I added in my database during the configuration of my server ?

Comment: That would be a Postgis connection. But I have no experience if that works out of a VM as well. I think this is worth a new question.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install QuickMapServices Plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/qms/)
2. Add your TMS source
3. Enjoy

[image: QMS settings]

[image: Add TMS Source]

Comment: Thanks, it looks great ! I'll try that. Is there any solutions on the server side that can fit in my case ? Like sharing directly a WMS URL ?

Comment: QGIS supports WMS from the scratch. On server side you need some server software i.e. NextGIS Web, GeoServer, etc. I would like to note what WMS is not TMS.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I just saw a mate who explained to me the difference too

Comment: FWIW, MapProxy is a good option if you want to support WMS given your pre-existing TMS.

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov what am I supposed to fill in the "ID" field ?

Comment: Just any unique text.

Comment: Are you sure ? I always get "Please, enter correct CRC ID" EDIT: It's okay now thanks

Comment: I suggest  you set CRS ID to `3857`, and check `Y origin top`.

Comment: @AndreJ is right, I think you asked about fist tab, where ID field also present. On TMS tab, you need the right EPSG code in CRS ID field.